# Math.sin(30*Math.PI/180) returns 0.49999999999999994 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I tried to calculate the sine of 30 degrees, just for testing and JS returns 0.49999999999999994.
The correct answer is 0.5.
Can someone explain why sometimes the calculation in JS going in such way?

Comment: It depends on how PI is defined. You are just seeing the result of the accuracy of the numbers on computers. PI has an infinite number of digits, but computer processors do not :)

Comment: So i must always use Math.round or something like that to correct such numbers?

Comment: No need to round. Just learn to live with the inaccuracies.